# Why does a computer's IP address change by minute that so quick?

Tags: perl, networking, ip-address

What could cause IP-addresses to be different in one computer?

My Perl variable `$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}` differs all the time. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Could you please try to reformulate your question? It is not very clear to me what your problem is.

Comment: Obviously, I used IP to check whether user's IP address is same all the while after login the system. Else, will show user error message.

Comment: See ysth's answer. You can _not_ rely on a 1:1 relationship of client machines to IP addresses. Proxying can put many clients on the same externally-visible IP address or move a single client to a different IP address for each request.

Comment: If the IP seems to change all the time, how can you know it's all the same client, and not multiple clients at different addresses? What does `ifconfig` (or the Windows equivalent; ISTR it's called `ipconfig`) say on the client?

Answer (score 5):

Most people do *not* have fixed IP addresses.  They may change daily, or when their connection to their ISP is reset, or all the time if they are behind some kind of proxying layer that may route requests through more than one system.

Comment: I understand that IP would be changed daily, but does IP possible to changed from minute to minute?

Comment: @deepWebMie: DHCP won't change IP addresses that quickly (it would break any type of connection-oriented protocol), but various proxying setups will. For example, AOL was well-known at one point for having a bank of outgoing proxies which would sometimes cause a user to, say, load a page with 4 images and have the five requests (page + each image) come in simultaneously from five different addresses.

Comment: Yes, AOL can (or used to anyway) cause changes from minute to minute, and there may be other similar situations.  And I believe someone using tor or the like will have this happen too.  Don't count on the IP address being the same; there's no good reason to do so anyway.

Comment: So that means the user may used proxy on his/her computer? So that caused its IP changed that quickly?

Comment: the user may have a proxy (either on or off his/her computer) or the user's isp may inflict a proxy

Answer (score 3):

REMOTE_ADDR refers to the client address, so would be different if you have multiple clients.

If you are testing with one client, perhaps your network interface has multiple IP addresses or you're observing this behavior over time when your IP has changed due to DHCP?

Comment: One client. Each client will get each of their IP address alone. 
Not too sure whether user IP changed due to DHCP. 
So obviously it could be due to DHCP?